# Proper way to define xsd schema in my situation

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<Item id="G1@MIT" type="GROUP">
   <Item id="B1@MIT" type="BLOCKSEGMENT"/>
   <Item id="S1@MIT" type="SWITCH"/>
</Item>
```

xml content above is an example of my xml data.
As you see I have Items that can contain other items.
My first question is how to define xml schema in this situation.
My second question is I want my id attribute to contain '@' character.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining recursive structures in XML Schema is trivial. It's just a matter of defining a type that contains an element of that type:

```
<xs:complexType name="ItemType">
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element name="Item" type="ItemType"></xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Attributes can contain the `@` character by default without any issues. If you want to force the attribute to contain that character then you should read up on [XML Schema restrictions](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp). In particular you'll want to look at the `xs:pattern` element.